# Symfony2 Add Column Doctrine for a query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, command

I have add a column on my DATABASE and i would use this field for a query but i receive this error

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 7 near 'pr_refer FROM': Error:
>   'pr_refer' is not defined.

How can i solved this problem? What should I write in the command line?

---

```
**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pr_refer", referencedColumnName="id")
 * */
private $pr_refer;
```

And set e get method

```
/**
 * Set pr_refer
 *
 * @param \Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User $PrRefer
 * @return UserReferences
 */
public function setPrRefer(\Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User $PrRefer = null) {
    $this->pr_refer = $PrRefer;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get pr_refer
 *
 * @return \Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User 
 */
public function getPrRefer() {
    return $this->pr_refer;
}
```

Where is the problem??

Comment: Please edit your question to show the query that throws this error.

Comment: The query is good but in my entity there isn't the field pr_refer.. How can i do?? @geoB

Comment: So... you can't select something that not exist. What would you like to do?

Comment: Yes i know, infact i would define this field add now in my db in Symfony entities.. Do you understand?? Sorry for my English  @Kevinrob

Comment: So bring up the entity file in your favorite editor and add the new property and mapping.  Or let doctrine do it for you: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#generating-getters-and-setters

Comment: yes, i try to write in my entity but i receive equals error.. Edit my post with entity @CERAD

Comment: Next step is to delete your cache directories.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` for adding the new field to the database.